# Split an address string but keep numbers within, in PostgreSQL with regex

Tags: regex, postgresql

We have the next SQL query in Postgresql 9.3

```
SELECT 
  regexp_split_to_array('merchant - mall', '(?!^)\s*(?!\d)[\-]\s*(?!\d)\s*(?=.)') as text1,
  regexp_split_to_array('merchant - street 245', '(?!^)\s*(?!\d)[\-]\s*(?!\d)\s*(?=.)') as text2,
  regexp_split_to_array('merchant - street-245', '(?!^)\s*(?!\d)[\-]\s*(?!\d)\s*(?=.)') as text3,
  regexp_split_to_array('merchant - street - 245', '(?!^)\s*(?!\d)[\-]\s*(?!\d)\s*(?=.)') as text4
```

The result is:

```
"{merchant,mall}","{merchant,street 245}","{merchant,street-245}","{merchant,street,245}"
```

The problem is that 4th sample considers the number as a separate string. Is there any way of doing this with regex in postgresql?

The regex used (in the query) is:

```
(?!^)\s*(?!\d)[\-]\s*(?!\d)\s*(?=.)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `\s*` in your negative lookahead assertion `(?!\d)`:

```
(?!^)\s*(?<!\d)[\-]\s*(?!\s*\d)\s*(?=.)
          ^              ^^
```

Or you can use the following simplified regex:

```
(?<!\d)\b[ -]+\b(?!\d)
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fY0fR6/8)

Comment: Great! And how would it be if original string will be 123-merchant?

Comment: It will be `{123,merchant}` what are you expecting?

Comment: As in 3rd and 4th cases, I expect it to stay with text: { 123-merchant}

Comment: Yes, it works properly in Python, but not in postgres where it seems that you can't use lookbehind assertions.

Comment: ohh ok... and you can use the above simplified regex inplace of previous one

Comment: I finally used this simplified version that worked well with all my test cases: `\s*[-]\s+(?!\s*\d\s*)`

Comment: Yes, it fails, thanks for the tip. But as it works with 123-merchant (without blanks), I have to take this while I figure out another more functional way of doing the split.